# make the .net framework compatible

Tags: .net, c++

I try to make an application that is build with .net framework version 3.5 on a machine with version 4.0 installed. To make this work you have to add

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

to the App.config file. But where is it? I cannot find any *.config file in my Visual Studio 2010 project folder?

Thanks,
Martin

ah I'm sorry - I'm using C++/CLI. There are Debug and Release subdirectories and I've added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true". Also, I had to add "copy app.config “$(TargetPath).config”" to post build events and finally I get a test.exe.config file :) But still the programm doesn't run on a Windows XP SP3 with the net framework 4 and the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable...

Answer (score 2):

You have to create it yourself.  Project + Add New Item, pick the "Application Configuration File" template.  Edit it.

You'll find it back in the bin\Debug folder after building.  Twice, `something.exe.config` that you deploy and `something.vshost.exe.config` that's used while debugging with the Visual Studio Hosting process option enabled.  Well, deploy the bin\Release folder content.

Comment: okay I've added the app.config file now. But after building there is no bin folder and no other *.config files appear as you said. Do I have to change compiler settings?

Comment: Oh, wait, you've tagged this C++.  I'll have to assume that you are actually using C++/CLI since regular C++ doesn't use the .NET framework at all.  Build output goes to the Debug and Release subdirectories, no bin.  You will also have to use the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" attribute in the `<startup>` element to make the assembly run on .NET 4.0  Be sure to test this.